# Show only the first x lines of csv/excel file in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a csv file which I convert, via a tmap to filter some things, to an excel file and I want to show only the first 16 lines of it. 
Where can I set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "tsamplerow" for that after the csv input with the code `"1..16"`

Answer (score 1):

In the input component property, set limit as 16.